# Get Transcript of YouTube Short

Tags: youtube

Last week I was able to open one of my shorts as a full video to get the transcript by right clicking and copying the URL, then visiting the URL in a new tab. Now that doesn't seem to work - it just opens as a short again. Anyone else noticed this change? How to get transcript for a short please?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]!  Please take the [Tour] and also review [ask].  Then [edit] the question to add enough detail to make it a good fit for this site so it can be reopened.  This resource may help you clarify your problem: [YouTube: Translate videos, subtitles, & captions](https://support.google.com/youtube/topic/9257536)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147540/discussion-on-question-by-robin-andrews-get-transcript-of-youtube-short); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.